# Heroku Python script booting two workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, heroku-cli

I have a python script on Heroku. Unfortunately Heroku always starts two workers.

Heroku Log:

```
2019-10-22T13:37:22.10522+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2019-10-22T13:37:22.150094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2019-10-22T13:37:22.811156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2019-10-22T13:37:22.836729+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2019-10-22T13:37:22.83692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:22 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-10-22T13:37:22.836978+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:22 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-10-22T13:37:22.937313+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-10-22T13:37:22.993203+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2019-10-22T13:37:25.047164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:bot`
2019-10-22T13:37:26.974115+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-10-22T13:37:26.974621+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:19216 (4)
2019-10-22T13:37:26.974717+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:26 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-10-22T13:37:26.978243+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:26 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-10-22T13:37:27.039502+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-22 13:37:27 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
```

Any idea what I can change?

Comment: Do you need any additional logs?